# Why Gun *gun=&machinegun is working, but *gun=&machinegun not?

Tags: c++, oop

I learn polymorphism in c++ and that's my code.

```
   class Gun
     {

       public:
       virtual void Shoot()
       {
          cout<<"BANG";
       }
      }

    class Machinegun:public Gun
 {

      public:
         void Shoot() override
        {
           cout<<"DRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR";
        }
     }

    int main()
    {
    Gun *gun;
    Machinegun machinegun;

    //Why I can't use      *gun=&machinegun;??????

    //It works when I write  Gun *gun=&machinegun;

    }
```

It's not the same thing  *gun=&machinegun<=>*gun=&machinegun; ???
I see no difference
Thanks

Comment: You don't see a difference between `Gun *gun=&machinegun` and `*gun=&machinegun;`?

Comment: `Gun *gun=&machinegun;` doesn't work either because it's a redefinition.

Comment: The pointer is part of the type; it means something different when you add a `*` to an already existing variable.  You want `gun = &machinegun;`.

Comment: The short answer here is simply that's because how C++ works. `*gun=&machinegun;` is not the same thing as `Gun *gun=&machinegun;`

Comment: what @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica i think what you to notice, is that when you do *gun you are dereferencing the gun pointer, so you are working on a object, and you are trying to assign to that object a reference to another one... instead you should do gun = &machinegun .. in Gun *gun=&machinegun; the * if the type of the gun element, when instead on just '*gun' is the operator

Comment: `Gun *` is the type.

Comment: In one case the star is part of the top declaration, in the other, it's a dereference operator. If you really don't understand the difference, I would suggest some of the excellent C++ tutorials available online.

Comment: Also, always show/read the errors when something doesn't work

Comment: learning c++ by trial and error can be done, but it is no fun, just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are confusing with the two uses of * .

```
Gun * gun
```

Here the * is used for defining a pointer of type Gun. Because it comes after the type Gun .

If you are using * on an already defined object(pointer types specifically), like your second example it means to dereference that pointer, what comes back is the object that the pointer referenced to , and in your case Gun. A Gun object cannot be assigned with Machinegun* type

What you probably wanted is

```
Machinegun machinegun;
Gun * gun;
gun = &machinegun;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong types in the left and right sides of the assignment

```
*gun=&machinegun;
```

The right side operand has the type `Machinegun *` (that is a pointer type) while the left side operand has the type `Gun`.

Instead write

```
gun = &machinegun;
```

In this case the pointer to the derived class will be implicitly converted (reinterpreted) to the pointer of the base class.

Another approach is to use a reference. For example

```
Machinegun machinegun;
Gun &gun = machinegun;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. in C++ you declare a pointer like this

int *name;

2. but to convert that pointer to the number it points to you use

*name

3. so when you use

gun* = &machinegun

you try to set the value pointed by gun as the pointer to 
   machinegun which throws an error because you can't just set 
   any value to a pointer

5. when you do

   Gun *gun = &machinegun

   you are making a pointer and setting the pointer to point at
   machine gun

What you are looking for is

gun = &machinegun

this sets gun which is a pointer to point to machinegun

below is a sample of code that I used to check my work

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int x = 100;           //create number
int* y = &x;           //creat pointer and point to number 


int main()
{
    y = &x;            //changing the value of an existing pointer
    cout << *y << endl;//printing out the value of number pointed to
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Gun *gun=&machinegun`

and

`Gun *gun; gun=&machinegun`

means creating new object of Gun type and assign them machinegun, but

`*gun=&machinegun`

is incorrect line, because of meaningless of `*gun=`

Comment: `*gun=` is not meaningless. It invokes the assignment operator of the `Machinegun` class.